# How to read/get ini file path in WCF published folder vb.net?

Tags: wcf, vb.net-2010

I'm writing a WCF service which suppose to get it's data connection to sql server from config file.

Where should I place the config file and how can I get it's path so every time the service will run it will go to the specific program application published folder and read the file from there.

when I publish the service I create a folder and in it there is XXX.svc file, Web.config file and bin folder.

Comment: If you're hosting in IIS, then the web.config will always be in the folder that holds the application.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: I need to read a different config.ini file,not web config (for example sql.ini).I host the service in IIS,how can I get the folder which contains this file.I'm going to have several services in my IIS and every published WCF folder will have a different sql.ini file.how can i configure each service  read the file from it's folder?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to turn .NET into something else. I suggest you do it the way .NET expects to do it and don't try to force it into some other pattern. What you suggest is simply not how .NET works.

Comment: Ok John,What are you suggesting since I'm relatively new in .net?

Comment: I suggest you publish each WCF service to a separate folder. Each folder will be a separate application or virtual directory in IIS. Each will have a web.config. Each web.config will contain a different connection string.

Comment: John, this is what i planned to do.if i need to create a file that will store other parameters to my service,should i create a different param config file  and put it in the published folder? If so,my question was how to retreive its path.

Comment: No. Put all configuration into the web.config. Now, FYI, for hosting in IIS, web.config are hierarchical. You have one in the application root, and can have one in each virtual folder and physical folder. The entries in the deeper files override the corresponding entries in the higher files. Other than that, don't think about separate files. It doesn't work that way.